# Changing Font on PDF Rotated Text

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iText to create barcodes on a PDF with the same format as this one:

[image: Barcode]

The problem is the the left number, the first zero digits must be smaller, while the rest of the numbers must also be bold. "T.T.C." also has to be even smaller (it doesn't have to be on another line).
I was able to rotate the number with the following code:

```
String price = "23000 T.T.C.";
PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate textTemplate = cb.createTemplate(50, 50);
ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(textTemplate);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(0, 0, 50, 50);
columnText.addElement(new Paragraph(price));
columnText.go();
Image image;
image = Image.getInstance(textTemplate);
image.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
image.setRotationDegrees(90);
doc.add(image);
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way online to change the font of certain characters of the String price when it is printed on the PDF.

Comment: Why not make it two Strings?

Comment: Also: why are you using `RUN_DIRECTION_RTL`. That only makes sense if you want to show Arabic or Hebrew in your text. And why do you mention HTML in the subject line of your question? Why doesn't the subject line mention bar codes? All in all, this is a very strange question.

Comment: @Nitek Adding three* strings would require coordination and positioning, I'll have to take into account that the number may have 3 zeroes or less/more, and 2 digits after it or less/more, I don't think i can take into account all the possibilities.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie
Because changing fonts in one string requires HTML, and the barcode works fine the problems is with he text on its left. Also removed the RUN_DIRECTION_RTL.

Comment: Why does changing font require HTML???

Comment: @Elio, you're going to have to explain the relationship with HTML a little more because I'm with Bruno, there's no HTML in the code and we see zero HTML processing instructions. If HTML is important enough to be in the title we'd expect there to be some HTML in the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small Proof of Concept that results in a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it has text in different sizes and styles. It also has a bar code that is rotated.

Take a look at the [RotatedText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/rotate-barcode#1564-rotatedtext.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(60, 120), 5, 5, 5, 5);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

    Font big_bold = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
    Font small_bold = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.BOLD);
    Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6);
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    p1.add(new Chunk("23", big_bold));
    p1.add(new Chunk("000", small_bold));
    document.add(p1);

    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("T.T.C.", regular);
    p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(p2);

    BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN();
    barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
    barcode.setCode("12345678");
    Rectangle rect = barcode.getBarcodeSize();
    PdfTemplate template = canvas.createTemplate(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight() + 10);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            new Phrase("DARK GRAY", regular), 0, rect.getHeight() + 2, 0);
    barcode.placeBarcode(template, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
    Image image = Image.getInstance(template);
    image.setRotationDegrees(90);
    document.add(image);

    Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("SMALL", regular);
    p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(p3);

    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

This example solves all of your issues:

- You want a `Paragraph` to use different fonts: compose a `Paragraph` using different `Chunk` objects.
- You want to add extra text on top of a bar code: add the bar code to a `PdfTemplate` and add the extra text using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` (not that you can also compose a `Phrase` using different `Chunk` objects if you need more than one font in that extra text).
- You want to rotate the bar code: wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object and rotate the image.

You can check the result: [rotated_text.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/objects/cmp_rotated_text.pdf)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bruno this is exactly what I needed thumbs up!