# Writing to absolute position while using direct content

Tags: itext

I am creating a pdf-document. First I add a table and some Texts to the PdfWriter. Now I want to add a costum template (including images and texts): I have to get the direct Content, which ist a layer over the PdfWriter-layer:

```
over= PdfWriter.getDirectContent();
```

I want to set the template exactly after the content on PdfWriter-layer. 
I can use

```
writer.getVerticalPosition(true)
```

for my calculation of y-Position on  PdfWriter-layer. 
This way I can add the costum template to the upper layer at that position. Now back to PdfWriter-layer how can I set the position of PdfWriter-layer after the tempalte on over-layer?!

Can somebody help? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing content added with `document.add()` and *direct content* us always a delicate operation. You need to know the height of the *custom template* and then add some white space that matches that height. However: what are you going to do if the content of the *custom template* doesn't match the page?

**I would advise against your plans, and I would recommend another approach.**

I am assuming that your custom template is a `PdfTemplate` object. In that case, you can wrap this object inside an `Image` object, and use `document.add()` to add the template.

See for instance: [Changing Font on PDF Rotated Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310018/changing-font-on-pdf-rotated-text)

In this example, we create a `PdfTemplate` with a bar code and some text:

```
PdfTemplate template = canvas.createTemplate(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight() + 10);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        new Phrase("DARK GRAY", regular), 0, rect.getHeight() + 2, 0);
barcode.placeBarcode(template, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

We want to add this `template` to a document with `document.add()`, so we wrap the template inside an `Image` object:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(template);
```

We can now add this image to the document:

```
document.add(image);
```

Afterwards, we can add extra content:

```
Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("SMALL", regular);
p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(p3);
```

That content is added under the `template` at the right position. You don't need to worry anymore about getting the Y position with `getVerticalPosition()` and you don't need to worry about setting the Y position after adding the template. If the template doesn't fit on the current page, it will automatically be moved to the next page.

**Important:** Maybe you are worried about the resolution of your template. You shouldn't be. If the template consists of vector data, wrapping that data inside an `Image` object won't change it into raster data. The vector data will be preserved. This is important in the bar code example, because you don't want the quality of your bar code to deteriorate by making it a raster image.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie: Thank you sooo much! You saved my day :)